# How can I add myself to the wheel group without using Sudo or Root commands?

Tags: macos, permissions, sudo

Right now I am sitting at work with the task to attempt to bypass permissions and do anything I shouldn't be able to. I have nothing but a standard User and Terminal. I don't know the administrator password/sudoers password and have no access to root. Any attempt I have made so far with commands such as `Chmod 755 /Users/ladmin` (ladmin is the administrator account). This is actually my job so I'm not breaking any rules here, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have access to root or access to sudo then what you want is not possible.  You don't mention what operating system you are using.

Comment: I have added the OSX tag since you mention `/Users`, please correct it if I'm wrong.

Comment: Do you have physical access to the box?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You can only add yourself to a group with root rights.

If it were possible to obtain root rights as a standard user, without knowing the root account's password, this would have been one of the biggest security flaws that ever existed, so you can reasonably expect that no Unix or Linux lets you do what you want.

For your record, the files responsible for this are, amongst others, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/passwd`, which are only writable by root itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the box could reboot it with a livecd/live usb and edit the sudoers file. If you can't reboot the box there is a possibility of finding a root exploit.

Comment: A root exploit for OS X? If the OP was capable of finding one, I'm sure they wouldn't have come to ask here.